# Spark: How to map an RDD when access to another RDD is required

Tags: scala, nested, apache-spark, transformation, rdd

Given two large key-valued pair RDDs (`d1` and `d2`), both composed of unique *ID* keys and *vector* values (e.g. `RDD[Int,DenseVector]`), I need to map `d1` in order to obtain for each of its element the *ID* of the closest element in `d2` using a euclidean distance metric between *vectors*.

I have not found a way to do it using standard RDD transformations. I understand that nested RDDs are not allowed in Spark, however, if it was possible, an easy solution would be:

```
d1.map((k,v) => (k, d2.map{case (k2, v2) => val diff = (v - v2); (k2, sqrt(diff dot diff))} 
                      .takeOrdered(1)(Ordering.by[(Double,Double), Double](_._2))      
                      ._1))
```

Moreover, if `d1` was small, I could work with a Map (e.g. `d1.collectAsMap()`) and loop over each of its elements, but this is not an option due to the dataset size.

Is there any alternative to this transformation in Spark?

**EDIT 1:**

Using @holden and @david-griffin suggestions I solved the issue using `cartesian()` and `reduceByKey()`. This is the script (assuming `sc` as the `SparkContext` and the use of the *Breeze* library).

```
val d1 = sc.parallelize(List((1,DenseVector(0.0,0.0)), (2,DenseVector(1.0,0.0)), (3,DenseVector(0.0,1.0))))
val d2 = sc.parallelize(List((1,DenseVector(0.0,0.75)), (2,DenseVector(0.0,0.25)), (3,DenseVector(1.0,1.0)), (4,DenseVector(0.75,0.0))))

val d1Xd2 = d1.cartesian(d2)
val pairDistances = d1Xd2.map{case ((k1, v1), (k2, v2)) => (k1, (k2, sqrt(sum(pow(v1-v2,2)))))}
val closestPoints = pairDistances.reduceByKey{case (x, y) => if (x._2 < y._2) x else y }

closestPoints.foreach(s => println(s._1 + " -> " + s._2._1))
```

The output obtained is:

```
1 -> 2
2 -> 4
3 -> 1
```

Comment: I would convert them to DataFrames, and try and do it with a `join` between the two. Otherwise, I think you have to do `d1.cartesian(d2)` and then use `reduce` to find the shortest distance for each `d1._1`

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29953122/21755

Comment: If both datasets are large, you cannot compare every element to every other element. You need to use a space partitioning scheme, then `join` the partitions and find the best matches within the partitions.

Comment: @Paul the answer you redirect to also works. It generalizes when the number of neighbors needed is more than one (e.g. for KNN).

Answer (score 2):

Transformations on RDDs can only be applied on the driver side, so nesting of maps won't work. As @davidgriffin points out you can use `cartesian`. For your use case you probably want to follow that up with `reduceByKey` and inside of your reduce by key you can keep track of the minimum distance.

Comment: I have updated the question with the solution based on your suggestion. Thank you.