# Spark AggregateByKey From pySpark to Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am transferring all my code over to scala and I had a function in pySpark that I have little clue on how to translate over to scala. Can anybody help and provide an explanation?
The PySpark looks like this:

```
.aggregateByKey((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                         lambda (sum, sum2, count), value: (sum + value, sum2 + value**2, count+1.0),
                         lambda (suma, sum2a, counta), (sumb, sum2b, countb): (suma + sumb, sum2a + sum2b, counta + countb))
```

Edit:
What I have so far is:

```
val dataSusRDD = numFilterRDD.aggregateByKey((0,0,0), (sum, sum2, count) =>
```

But what I am having trouble understanding is how you write this in scala because of the group of functions being then designating the value into a group of actions (sum + value, etc). into the second aggregating functions all with the proper syntax. Its hard to coherently state my troubles in this scenario. Its more so I not understanding of scala and when to use the brackets, vs parentheses, vs, comma

Comment: SO is't really a code translation service. Where are you stuck? What bits do you not understand?

Comment: Added an edit that explains my thoughts,

Comment: There's a Scala example of aggregateByKey in an answer I wrote here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29953122/21755. Starting by writing non-anonymous functions will probably make the learning curve a little less steep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @paul suggests using named functions might make understanding whats going on a bit simpler.

```
val initialValue = (0.0,0.0,0.0)
def seqOp(u: (Double, Double, Double), v: Double) = (u._1 + v, u._2 + v*v, u._3 + 1)
def combOp(u1: (Double, Double, Double),  u2: (Double, Double, Double)) = (u1._1 + u2._1, u1._2 + u2._2, u1._3 + u2._3)
rdd.aggregateByKey(initialValue)(seqOp, combOp)
```

Comment: Hello, I am getting the following issue: scala> val dataStatsRDD = numFilterRDD.aggregateByKey(initialValue, seqOp, combOp)
<console>:38: error: too many arguments for method aggregateByKey: (zeroValue: U)(seqOp: (U, Double) => U, combOp: (U, U) => U)(implicit evidence$3: scala.reflect.ClassTag[U])org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, U)]
       val dataStatsRDD = numFilterRDD.aggregateByKey(initialValue, seqOp, combOp)

Comment: My bad, I forgot that its passed with partial application in Scala. I've updated the answer. `rdd.aggregateByKey(initialValue)(seqOp, combOp)
`